# why does an array with a property cause an undefined error in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

This syntax works fine:

```
var foo = [];
foo[0] = "do";
foo[1] = "re";
```

I'm trying to do the same using properties, like so.

```
var foo = [{
    note: "",
}]; 
foo[0].note = "do";
foo[1].note = "re";
```

But in this case the last line now generates an undefined variable error. What am doing wrong?

**Update:**

Just responding to the comment that my question could be clearer. The problem comes up, e.g., when I try to assign values to an array in a for-loop, where i is the index, with something like

```
foo[i] = i
```

but when using an array element with a property, like

```
foo[i].note = i
```

it won't work because, as nnnnnn says, the element doesn't exist yet as soon as the index hits 1. So is the answer that I just can't assign values to array elements in a for-loop like that and I have to use a variable like fooNote[i] instead?

Comment: Note that it's not "an array with a property", it is an array *element* with a property. (In this case an element that doesn't exist, hence the "undefined" error you mention.)

Comment: In browsers consistent with ECMA-262 ed 3, the comma after `note: "",` will throw an error, however more recent versions of ECMA-262 allow a trailing comma in an object literal to be ignored.

Comment: `foo[1] = {note: 're'}`

Answer (score 1):

You need the index 1 as well:

```js
var foo = [{
    note: "",
},
{
    note:"" //note property for foo[1] is now set here
}]; 
foo[0].note = "do";
foo[1].note = "re";

console.log(foo);
```

Your original array didn't have the index 1 set.

Comment: I think OP's question is about dynamically creating properties.

Comment: It didn't seem to me that it was the case, he seemed to be trying to understand what caused the error. But then again i may have misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 0):

Your foo variable has only one element, in this case

```
{
note: "",
}
```

so when you try to access to the index [1] this result on a undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add object dynamically but only one level at a time.
Hence when you say `foo[1] = 're'` you are dynamically creating slot 1 and assigning it the value of 're'. But `foo[1].note = 're'` is trying to create slot 1 and a property `note` that does not work. You could do `foo[1] = {note: 're'};`that will create slot 1 dynamically and separately an object to assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

you get undefined because `foo[1]` is undefined, it does not exists, doing something like this `foo[1].note` does not make sense because `undefined` is not an object

```js
 var foo = [{
    note: "",
}]; 

foo[0].note = "do";

Object.assign(foo[1] = {}, { note: "re" });

console.log(foo[1].note);
```

`Object.assign` copies the members of an object into another object, in the above code `foo[1]` was set to an object, before coping `{note: "re"}` to `foo[1]`

Comment: Isn't `Object.assign()` a rather roundabout way to say `foo[1] = { note: "re" }`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you think that you are declaring an array of objects with a property `note`. You can't really do that in javascript, you can write it for future reference only as it is totally valid to override it with something completely different.

In your case foo[0] exists while foo[1] doesn't. You're trying to affect a value to an non existing property, hence the error.
When you do `var foo = [{note:""}];` you actually have an array of length 1. You can access foo[0] but foo[1] is still undefined. You need to assign a value to it.

```
var foo = [{note: ""}]; // {note:""} is here for reference;
foo[0].note = "do"; // or foo[0] = {note: "do"};
foo[1] = {note: "re"};
```